# PayPal related policy and integration

Tags: php, paypal

I am currently developing an auction website and I am wondering if I can hold payments. I need to do this to avoid unfair deals. For example:

> A seller didn't deliver the item to the buyer. I need to hold the
>   payment and then once the buyer has confirmed that the item has been
>   delivered the payment will be transferred to the account of the
>   seller. Is there any possible way to attain this logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I could suggest is to make use of [Authorization and Capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/) in PayPal.
It uses Express Checkout API which can be achieved in order to delay the order fullfillment. Authorization & Capture, or Auth/Capture, allows you to authorize the availability of funds for a transaction but delay the capture of funds until a later time. This is often useful for merchants who have a delayed order fulfillment process

Comment: Thanks for the reply..really appreciate it..I am currently reading the   paypal documentation..